# Conversion from single to circular linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, circular-list

Here is the [link](http://codepad.org/jTr5IqlU) to the code I wrote for circular linked list.  The code is pasted below also.

```
typedef struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
}mynode;

mynode *head, *tail, *temp,*sp,*fp;

void add(int value); 
void iterative_reverse();
void print_list();
void findcycle();

int main()
{
    head=(mynode *)0;
    add(1);
    add(2);
    add(3);
    //print_list();
    findcycle();
    return(0);
}

void add(int value)
{
    temp = (mynode *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->value=value;
    temp->next=(mynode *)0;
    if(head==(mynode *)0)
    {
        head=temp;
        tail=temp;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next=temp;
        tail=temp;
        tail->next=head;
        temp->next=head;
    }
}

void findcycle()
{
    if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL)
        printf("null");
    sp=head;
    fp=head->next;
    while (fp != NULL && fp->next != NULL)
    {
        if ((fp == sp) || (fp->next == sp))
                printf("Cycle");
        sp = sp->next;
        fp = fp->next->next;
    }
    printf("Not a Cycle");
}

void print_list()
{
    for(temp=head; temp!=tail; temp=temp->next)
        printf("[%d]->",(temp->value));
}
```

I had initially written it for single and then changed few pointers to make it circular. I am doing some mistake in it which I am not able to track and hence getting a Timeout. Please suggest.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks wrong:

```
tail->next=temp;
tail=temp;
tail->next=head;
temp->next=head;
```

It should be (if you're adding the new node at the end of the list and want it to be a circular list, like I'm assuming here):

```
tail->next=temp;
temp->next=head;
tail=temp;
```

It's a minor error, anyway: only a redundant assignment.

The really serious trouble is here:

```
void findcycle()
{
if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL)
            printf("null");
sp=head;
fp=head->next;
while (fp != NULL && fp->next != NULL)
 {
        if ((fp == sp) || (fp->next == sp))
                printf("Cycle");
        sp = sp->next;
        fp = fp->next->next;
 }
printf("Not a Cycle");
}
```

First of all, what are you trying to accomplish? It isn't clear, so it isn't easy to suggest you how to correct it; the most obvious bug, anyway, is that if the list actually *is* a circular one, then the loop will go on forever, as there is no exit condition that can ever happen (no one of the pointers will ever become NULL).

Comment: @vartika: then you should upvote and/or accept the best answer.

Comment: Both the answers suggested the same but yes this was more detailed explanation. How do I upvote?

Comment: By clicking on the up arrow above the number on the left of the answer. You can upvote more than one answer if you like them both. To downvote one answer you don't like, click on the down arrow. To mark one answer as accepted, click on the little icon below the down arrow.

Answer (score 0):

When `findcycle` finds a cycle, it doesn't exit: it just keeps going. (Likewise when it gets a list with 0 or 1 elements.) I do not guarantee that this is the only error in your code, but it suffices to make it not work.